# Move point inwards while counting number of nested parentheses without throwing an error

Tags: list, motion, parentheses

I would like to write a function that counts the number of nested parentheses while moving the cursor to the innermost bracket without throwing an error.

```
  (defun count-and-move ()
    (interactive)
    (setq c 0)
    (while t
      (down-list)
      (incf c)))
```

If we run this code, the cursor would eventually reach the innermost bracket.

> |「「「「」」」」 --> 「「「「|」」」」

After which it throws an error:

> down-list: Scan error: "Containing expression ends prematurely", 254, 255

What should the condition for `while` be so that the movement stops automatically when the cursor has reached the innermost point?

In human language, it would be something like: 
"Keep running `(down-list)` and increase counter by 1 until the cursor is stuck." OR
"Break out of loop if `(down-list)` is going to throw an error!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `down-list` and its worker `scan-lists` there doesn't appear to be an option to *prevent* the error, so we would need to handle it somehow.

In some instances, a simplistic use of `ignore-errors` is fine.  E.g.:

```el
(ignore-errors (down-list))
```

In this instance that's problematic, because `down-list` will return `nil` even when it works, so we probably want to handle the error; although you *could* use the non-movement of point instead:

```el
(if (eql (point) (progn (ignore-errors (down-list)) (point)))
    didn't move
  moved)
```

If we want to handle the error explicitly, we can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `toggle-debug-on-error` to find out what we're dealing with.  Here we learn:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (scan-error "Containing expression ends prematurely" 359 360)
  (scan-lists 359 1 -1)
  (down-list 1)
  (funcall-interactively down-list 1)
  (call-interactively down-list)
  (repeat nil)
  (funcall-interactively repeat nil)
  (call-interactively repeat nil nil)
  (command-execute repeat)
```

So the error to handle is `scan-error`.

We can handle errors using `condition-case`, like so:

```el
(condition-case err
    (down-list)
  (scan-error (message "Scan error: %S" err)))
```

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Handling Errors` for details.

Comment: I don't see any reason to not use `ignore-errors` in this particular case. You actually beat me in answering the question for a second and I considered not posting my answer at all. But after reading yours in full I thought the question deserved a straight simple answer. I think we should keep both our answers -- one deeper / one straight and simple.

Comment: Yes, your usage of `ignore-errors` is better than mine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ignore-errors`. You should also use `let` instead of `setq` for `c` to keep the scope of `c` local.

```el
(defun count-and-move ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((c 0))
    (ignore-errors
      (while t
        (down-list)
        (incf c)))
    c))
```

Comment: Yes, I like this answer very much as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just use this.  But all of the answers provided so far are pretty much the same.  The idea is, in each iteration, to increment and return the counter but "handle" a `down-list` error by returning `nil`.  `ignore-errors` returns `nil` for an error or whatever evaluating its arg returns - in this case, the counter value, `c`.

```lisp
(defun count-and-move ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((c  0))
    (while (ignore-errors (progn (down-list) (incf c))))))
```

The `ignore-errors` returns the result of the `progn`, which returns the result of `incf`, which is non-`nil`. But if `down-list` raises an error then `ignore-errors` returns `nil`. The `while` evaluates its body as long as the test (the `ignore-errors`) returns non-`nil`. So it stops when `down-list` raises an error.

Comment: Can you explain if or how your solution differs from Tobias in terms of thinking and performance? You omitted the `t` condition of `while` and used `progn` to handle `(down-list)` and  `(incf c)`.

Comment: The last sentence, or the last 2, before the code explain it. But I've added additional explanation now, to make it even clearer. But as I said, all of the answers are essentially the same.